# Linux passive waiting for signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

I am trying to make process wait, if certain condition is not met. If condition changes over time, I would like process to wake up and continue to do it's job.

I tried to do it this way:

```
  ... if(condition_false)
  {
   signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
   pause();
  } ...

  function handler(int signum)
  {
   if(signum == SIGUSR1)
   {
    //do stuff...
   }
  }

  kill(proc_pid,SIGUSR1);
```

Problem with this is, that my code seems too complex and pause does not work as expected. Additionally I would like to print message if the signal triggers and handler just does not offer this option directly.

So my question is: is there alternative to such sleep/wake approach?

Comment: What do you mean that `pause` "does not work as expected"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you want your process (or thread) to wait (sleep) until a signal is delivered, use [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html).